# Why does NSURLSession seemingly timeout when this isn't necessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

Back when I used `NSURLConnection` to do my `restAPI` requests everything was fine. Now that `NSURLSession` is here and `NSURLConnection` is deprecated I decided to implement `NSURLSession`. I really like using it, but every 4-5 or so times I run my app the request to my token page on the `API` times out. This page is a very simple `php` page that gives me back a `json` body with an access token, a refresh token and a refresh interval. I tried doing the request using a `browser` and it never timed out. I also tried using `NSURLConnection` again and this also never times out. What's so different with `NSURLSession` that it can't handle a simple request?

Here is my code:

```
static BOOL logCallbacks = NO;

static NSString* authUrl = @"****";
static NSString* apiUrl = @"****";

static NSURLSession *session;
static NSString* apiKey = @"****";
static NSString* apiSecret = @"****";

static NSString* accessToken = @"";
static NSString* refreshToken = @"";

static NSMutableDictionary* taskCompletionHandlerMap;
static NSMutableDictionary* taskBuffer;

@implementation APIclient

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark helpers

- (NSURLSession*) session {

    if (!taskCompletionHandlerMap) {
        taskCompletionHandlerMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        taskBuffer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    if (!session) {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0;
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0;
        sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;

        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    }

    return session;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest*) baseRequestUsingUrl:(NSString*)url {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bearer %@", accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];

    return request;
}

- (NSData*) jsonFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void) InitAPIByUsername:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password completionHandler:
    (void (^)(NSDictionary* json))completionHandler {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self baseRequestUsingUrl:authUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[username,     password,       @"password",    apiKey,         apiSecret]
                                                                                               forKeys:@[@"username",  @"password",    @"grant_type",  @"client_id",   @"client_secret"]]
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil]];

    NSURLSessionTask* task = [[self session] dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [taskCompletionHandlerMap setObject:completionHandler forKey:task];
    task.taskDescription = @"auth";
    [task resume];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark callbacks

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didBecomeInvalidWithError:(nullable NSError *)error {
    if (logCallbacks || error) NSLog(@"%s -> error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}

- (void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:
    (void (^)(NSURLRequest * __nullable))completionHandler {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task needNewBodyStream:
    (void (^)(NSInputStream * __nullable bodyStream))completionHandler {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(nullable NSError *)error {
    if (logCallbacks || error) NSLog(@"%s -> error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

    if ([taskCompletionHandlerMap objectForKey:task] && [taskBuffer objectForKey:task]) {
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[taskBuffer objectForKey:task] options:0 error:nil];
        [taskBuffer removeObjectForKey:task];

        if (json) {
            if ([task.taskDescription isEqualToString:@"auth"]) {
                accessToken = [[json objectForKey:@"value"] objectForKey:@"access_token"];
                refreshToken = [[json objectForKey:@"value"] objectForKey:@"refresh_token"];
            }

            void (^ completionHandler)(NSDictionary*) = [taskCompletionHandlerMap objectForKey:task];
            [taskCompletionHandlerMap removeObjectForKey:task];
            completionHandler(json);
        }
    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:
    (void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didBecomeDownloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didBecomeStreamTask:(NSURLSessionStreamTask *)streamTask {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if ([taskBuffer objectForKey:dataTask]) {
        NSMutableData* d = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[taskBuffer objectForKey:dataTask]];
        [d appendData:data];
        [taskBuffer setObject:d forKey:dataTask];
    } else {
        [taskBuffer setObject:data forKey:dataTask];
    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)proposedResponse completionHandler:
    (void (^)(NSCachedURLResponse * __nullable cachedResponse))completionHandler {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    completionHandler(proposedResponse);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes {
    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:
    (void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {

    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"challenge error: %@", challenge.error);
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:
    (void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {

    if (logCallbacks) NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"challenge error: %@", challenge.error);
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
}

@end
```

Then I use the following to get my tokens:

```
[APP InitAPIByUsername:self.txt_username.text password:self.txt_password.text completionHandler:^(NSDictionary* json) {

    if (!json || [[json objectForKey:@"value"] objectForKey:@"error"]) {
        [self APIRequest:@"init_api" onError:json];
    } else {
        [self onInitAPIComplete:json];
    }
}];
```

Comment: You should avoid static variables (at least for things that area actually variables) and instead use instance variables or properties. Any specific reason for `sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;`? Are you sure you don't have any other long-running connections to the same host? Your `jsonFromDictionary` actually returns an `NSString`, not `NSData`. Why use delegates and manage buffers and completion handlers yourself? Just use `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:`, it'll shorten your code a lot!

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for the feedback. My HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost  is 1 because the example code used 1, I'm not 100% sure what it does but I'll try setting it higher. What is a sane number? jsonFromDictionary definitely returns an NSData* object (dataUsingEncoding returns NSData*) or nil. I did not know there was a callback mechanism implemented, that's why I did it myself, but I don't think that's the issue at hand. The only thing that happens when it times out is URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError is called with the error 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."'

Comment: @jcaron Setting the HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost  to a higher number greatly improves my app's performance. So thanks a lot for that :). But I still get timeouts sometimes... It seems so random, I just don't get it.

Comment: Unless you have specific requirements, just use the defaults. Most of your code can be reduced to just a few lines by using the `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` and `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:`. Indeed, your `jsonFromDictionary` returns `NSData` (I hadn't scrolled enough), but what's the purpose of converting to string and back, using the same encoding? Just `return jsonData;`...

Comment: @jcaron I used to do that, the conversion is a bug-fix. Something with the original containing weird characters, which is solved by doing the conversion and back.

Comment: We're talking about the output of `NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`... No weird characters possible, just good valid JSON, which is 100% pure 7 bits.

Comment: Do you get the same timeouts in the simulator and on actual devices? Did you not maybe set the link conditioner to simulate "bad" network conditions? Have you tried sniffing the traffic to see what goes through? Are there not situations where you have lots of data to send (or receive) over a slow link?

Comment: The only time it happens is the very first request that the app does, and not always. Simulator has the same problem and no developer options are turned on. I haven't checked the network traffic yet. The current request that the app always does is a very simple http request to a php page. The app send a username and password in the body and the API returns a json with three values. The total amount of bytes sent back and forth here is not more than 100, excluding headers and other overhead.